# TypeError - d is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using jQuery child rows to display some data within a parent row. After displaying initially via Ajax, I do another ajax request and change data in the datatable. Now, if I try to expand it, it shows the rows. However, if I again try to change data in the datatable, it says d is not defined.

Here is my code when I initially load data in the datatable.

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: "GetGridDetails?decodeID="+decoderFileSelected,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (myData) {
            if(myData != null){

                console.log("my data is:"+myData);

                    var table = $('#dashNumTable').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    data: myData ,
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "className":      'details-control',
                            "orderable":      false,
                            "data":           null,
                            "defaultContent": ''
                        },
                        { "data": "S" },
                        { "data": "W" },
                        { "data": "SA" },
                        { "data": "DDS" },
                        { "data": "AAS" },
                        { "data": "ABS" },
                        { "data": "BIN" },
                        { "data": "ET" }
                    ],
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                });

             // Add event listener for opening and closing details
                $('#dashNumTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                    //alert("clicked plus!");
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var row = table.row(tr);
                    //var row = $('#dashNumTable').DataTable().row(tr);

                    if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        // This row is already open - close it
                        row.child.hide();
                        tr.removeClass('shown');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Open this row
                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                        tr.addClass('shown');
                    }
                  });

            }//if code ends..
            else{
                alert("There are no base numbers for the selected decoder ring file...");
            }

        } //end of success function...


    });
```

This generates table with a plus button to expand and minus button to contract.

Code to refresh and add new data when an ajax event is fired.

```
$(document).on("click", "#showHGAPartBtn", function(){
        // clear the eixisting table contents
        //alert("show button clicked!");
        var decoderFileSelected = $("#decoderFile").val();
        //$('#dashNumTable').empty();
        // var clearTable = $('#dashNumTable').DataTable();
        // clearTable.clear().draw();   
        //clearTable.rows().remove();
        $('#dashNumTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        //get the fresh data..
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "GetGridDetails?decodeID="+decoderFileSelected,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //if(myData != null){
                    //console.log("my data is:"+myData);
                    var table = $('#dashNumTable').DataTable({
                        // destroy: true,
                        cache: false,
                        processing: true,
                        data: data ,
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "className":      'details-control',
                                "orderable":      false,
                                "data":           null,
                                "defaultContent": ''
                            },
                            { "data": "S" },
                            { "data": "W" },
                            { "data": "SA" },
                            { "data": "DDS" },
                            { "data": "AAS" },
                            { "data": "ABS" },
                            { "data": "BIN" },
                            { "data": "ET" }
                        ],
                        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                    });

                 // Add event listener for opening and closing details
//                  $('#dashNumTable').on('click', 'tbody td.details-control', function () {
                    $('#dashNumTable').delegate('tbody td.details-control', 'click', function () {
                        //alert("clicked plus!");
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        //table.ajax.reload();
                        var row = table.row(tr);
//                      alert("Row is :"+row);
                        //var row = $('#dashNumTable').DataTable().row(tr);
                        console.log(tr);
                        console.log(row);
                        console.log(row.child.isShown());
                        if (row.child.isShown()) {
                            // This row is already open - close it
                            row.child.hide();
                            tr.removeClass('shown');
                        }
                        else {
                            // Open this row
                            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                            tr.addClass('shown');
                        }
                      });

           //   }//if code ends..
            //  else{
                //  alert("There are no base numbers for the selected decoder ring file...");
                //}

            },
            //end of success function...
            error: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }

        });// end of AJAX call
```

Here is the format function, which returns error in *second* time.

```
function format (d) {
            //alert(d.stringify);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(d));
            var rowSelectedBaseNumbers = d.HGA_BASE_NUMBERS;
            // `d` is the original data object for the row
            //alert(rowSelectedBaseNumbers);
            var selectedBaseNumbersDropdown = $("#selBaseNumbers").val();
            var initial = "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='innerDataTbl'><tr class='shown'> <th>Dash No.</th> <th>Heads</th>";
            var finalReturn = "";
            var endHeaders = "</tr>";
            var middleContentHeaders = "";
            //iterate over the base numbers now
            for(var i=0;i< selectedBaseNumbersDropdown.length; i++){
                middleContentHeaders += "<th>"+selectedBaseNumbersDropdown[i]+"</th>";
            }

            var beginTRCheckboxes = "<tr><td>"+d.DIGIT+0+","+d.DIGIT+1+"</td><td>Up,Dn</td>";
            var endTRCheckboxes = "</tr>";
            var endTable = "</table>";
            //iterate over the total base numbers again to create respective checkboxes
            var checkboxes = "";
            for(var i=0;i< selectedBaseNumbersDropdown.length; i++){
                //is the selected base number already selected?
                if($.inArray(selectedBaseNumbersDropdown[i], rowSelectedBaseNumbers) == -1){
                    //not found
                    //display checkbox as it is
                    checkboxes += "<td><input type='checkbox'/></td>";
                }
                else{
                    //found
                    //mark checkbox already selected
                    checkboxes += "<td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' disabled/></td>"
                }
            }

            //generate final return now
            finalReturn = initial+middleContentHeaders+endHeaders+beginTRCheckboxes+checkboxes+endTRCheckboxes+endTable;
            return finalReturn;
        }
```

The error returned is

> typeerror - d is not defined

Comment: What does `console.log(row.data())` show?

Comment: Somewhere in your table, `row.data()` is returning `undefined`, thus not giving the function `fortmat()` the `d` to work with.

Comment: @mplungjan
Trying to find it. It seems that control isn't even going into the if / else block.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo
Any idea why it's happening? Or any other better ways to delete everything in the table which was displayed and display new rows with ajax?

Comment: @mplungjan
The output of that is [object Object] for the first time I hit ajax call, and `undefined` for the second time.

Comment: You could start by checking the table itself if it has any blank rows.
If it does, then you need to be sure it doesn't. 
Check if all the values are being get properly, else the problem may be in your ajax. Or may even be that when you change the values on the datatable, you are missing a row or the code is not changing it properly. Hard to tell without being able to really see the response from the ajax.

Answer (score 1):

make a failSafe scenario in your format function for whenever no data is available, the code will not execute.

```
function format (d) {
  if (d) { return null; }
  ...
}
```

Are you sure that the code

> row.data()

actually returns a value? => Try to figure that out.

Also, what is d? Try to make your code as easy as possible to read. We developers are writers. Not for the computer, but for our colleagues who sometimes need to read our code to understand what we are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Making your code fail safe is always nice, but this is just a bandaid for the actual underlying problem in this case..

Comment: @LaurensMäkel, might I say that I recommended to check if the value from row.data() existed in the first place.